# Is there a way I can read two char from the istringstream?

Tags: c++, stack

I am trying to write a function postFixEval for stack based evaluation of postfix expressions. The program reads postfix expressions and prints their values. Each input expression is entered on its own line, and the program will terminate when the user enters a blank line. Assuming that there are only binary operations and that the expressions contain no variables. I am using a stack.

Example,

`50 6 +`

`89 6 + 9 2 - /`

Currently I am trying to solve only the addition function, which is:
`1 2 +`.

I am getting the correct addition value when I am trying to use single digit numbers however I am not able to work with 2 digit number.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stack>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

//skipWhiteSpace for skipping whitespace in an input stream

void skipWhiteSpace(istream& in)
{
    while (in.good() && isspace(in.peek()))
    {
        // Read and discard the space character
        in.ignore();
        in.get();
    }
}

int postFixEval(string str)
{
    istringstream in = istringstream(str);
    stack<int> postFixStack;
    skipWhiteSpace(in);

    while (in)
    {
        int num = in.peek();

        //checking if the instream is a digit or not
        if (isdigit(num)) {
            postFixStack.push(in.get());
        }
        else {

            char op = in.get();
            if (op == '+') {

                int num1 = postFixStack.top();
                num1 = num1 - '0';
                postFixStack.pop();

                int num2 = postFixStack.top();
                num2 = num2 - '0';
                postFixStack.pop();

                postFixStack.push(num1 + num2);
            }
        }
    }
    return postFixStack.top();
}

int main()
{
    string input;

    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Enter a postfix expression, or press ENTER to quit:\n";
        getline(cin, input);

        if (input.length() == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        int number = postFixEval(input);
        cout << "The value of " << input << " is " << number << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output of `78 5 +` to be `83`. However I am getting `13`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expect the output of 78 5 + to be 83. However I am getting 13.

This happens because you put digits into stack instead of numbers. So after reaching operator + stack has state {7, 8, 5}. You pop last two elements (5 and 8) and get 13 = 5 + 3.

To fix that just use `stack<int>` for storing numbers:

```
int postFixEval(string str)
{
    istringstream in = istringstream(str);
    stack<int> postFixStack;
    skipWhiteSpace(in);

    while (in)
    {
        char ch = in.peek();
        if (isdigit(ch)) {
            int num;
            in >> num;
            postFixStack.push(num);
        }
        else {
            char op = in.get();
            if (op == '+') {
                int num1 = postFixStack.top();
                postFixStack.pop();
                int num2 = postFixStack.top();
                postFixStack.pop();
                postFixStack.push(num1 + num2);
            }
        }
    }
    return postFixStack.top();
}
```

UPD: Let me explain the difference between `peek()` and `operator>>()`.

1) [Peek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/peek/) returns the next character from stream, without extracting it. So if stream contains '78', `peek()` will return int code of character '7', which is equal to 55.

2) [Operator>>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/), which is used in expression `{in >> num}` with an integer type, parses a sequence of characters from stream (until first whitespace or end of line) and interprets them as integer value.

Comment: Is there a way I can do this using only ```stack<int>``` for numbers?

Comment: Yes, only one stack is enough. I fixed answer.

Comment: would it be possible to understand how you did it? If the peek is only getting one character. How is the num getting one number from the stream?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading in a single digit with

```
    if (isdigit(num)) {
        postFixStack.push(in.get());
    }
```

read in an integral value:

```
    if (isdigit(num)) {
        int number;
        in >> number;
        postFixStack.push(number);
    }
```

Comment: I am using the peek() to read the characters. If I change my solution to what you suggest I am getting:
```10 2 +``` = ```-84```

Comment: `peek` gives you a single character (which could be a digit), but it leaves this character in the stream. In your program, you actually read the characters only with `get`.